# Output of sqlite3.exe is different in Powershell and Command Line

Tags: powershell, command-line

My problem is with exporting output file in pipelines with PowerShell.

I have a task in task scheduler with a PowerShell script but my output file (newtest.txt) with charset is different in PowerShell and in Command line.

It´s a problem with sqlite3.exe and codepage. The language is czech. Active codepage is 852 (I run "chcp") but when I run `$Outputencoding` in Powershell ISE I get this:

```
sSingleByte      : True
BodyName          : iso-8859-2
EncodingName      : Středoevropské jazyky (Windows)
HeaderName        : windows-1250
WebName           : windows-1250
WindowsCodePage   : 1250
IsBrowserDisplay  : True
IsBrowserSave     : True
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalEncoderBestFitFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalDecoderBestFitFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 1250
```

Code in Powershell script:

```
C:\sqlite3 -separator ';' places.sqlite "select moz_places.url, moz_places.title from moz_places where moz_places.title like '%' >> test1.txt
gc test1.txt | sort | get-unique > newtest.txt
copy newtest.txt test1.txt
```

And charset´s example of output file "newset.txt" is terrible:

> Facebook â€“ pĹ™ihlaste se, nebo se zaregistrujte Seznam - najdu tam,
>   co neznĂˇm

Code in Command Line (when I run only sqlite with parameters):

```
C:\sqlite3 -separator ; places.sqlite "select moz_places.url, moz_places.title from moz_places where moz_places.title like '%' >> test1.txt
```

And charsets is perfect in output file:

> Facebook – přihlaste se, nebo se zaregistrujte Seznam - najdu tam, co
>   neznám

I need correct charsets in Powershell script, thank you for your advices.

Comment: It works: [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8

Comment: Does it possible UTF8 without BOM, also UTF8 NO BOM? Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Powershell is used?

Comment: Version 5.1.17763.316